# How to add components inside panel header and footer in react-bootstrap?

Tags: react-bootstrap

In classic bootstrap, this construction is easy:

```
<div class="panel panel-danger">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    Some HTML including a drop-down.
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel body, lots of HTML here
  </div>
  <div class="panel-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-default">Click me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the react-bootstrap implementation, there seems to be no way of including further html in the panel header or footer?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  <Panel 
    header="Some HTML including a drop-down." 
    footer={<Button> Click me</Button>} 
    bsStyle="danger"
  >
    Panel body, lots of HTML here
  </Panel>
```

You can use other props from bootstrap-react [document](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#panels-props)

Comment: but but ... it's sooo ugly!

Answer (score 1):

As per the [react-bootstrap panel documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/panel/):

```
<Panel>
    <Panel.Heading>Panel heading</Panel.Heading>
    <Panel.Body>Panel content</Panel.Body>
    <Panel.Footer>Panel footer</Panel.Footer>
</Panel>
```